# Using custom certificates for Authorize.net AIM API in Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, authorize.net, activemerchant

As of a few days ago, Authorize.net [upgraded their certificates so that they are signed using (SHA-2)](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Production-Certificate-Upgrades-begin-May-27-2015/bc-p/50439#M460).

Our customers now get this error returned from Authorize.net:

`SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`

So I need to use them in our Rails app on Heroku.  Heroku's set of root certificates doesn't include these, so I have to include them in ActiveMerchant, but am having no luck finding clear instructions for how to do this properly.  Here's what I've tried so far:

I've downloaded the five root certificates Authorize.net requires, and chained them together as "cacert.pem," replacing the existing "cacert.pem" file in my app's `/vendor/plugins/active_merchant/lib/certs/` folder (I backed up the old `cacert.pem` file first, just in case).  That by itself did not solve the problem -- I still get the same error in development.

Looking at the new "cacert.pem" file I created, I saw that the last certificate in the chain (https://cacert.omniroot.com/bc2025.crt) looked like this:

``` 0Çw0Ç_†��π0
    *ÜHÜ˜
�0Z10   UIE10U
    Baltimore10U
CyberTrust1"0 UBaltimore CyberTrust Root0
000512184600Z
250512235900Z0Z10   UIE10U
    Baltimore10U
CyberTrust1"0 UBaltimore CyberTrust Root0Ç"0
    *ÜHÜ˜
�Ç�0Ç
Ç�£ª"´ò=WË&röµy‘)‚·ËïÄ±∞„[é+)ödﬂ°]Ì∞    m€(.Œb¢b˛¥à⁄Î8Î!ù¿A+R{àw”è«∫πàµj    ÁsË@ß—Ã bç-Âè¶P“®P√(Íı´%áäöñ©g∏?’˜˘R/¬’ppè¿ Àö·Ÿ 3zw÷¯ÏπÒhDBH“¿¬§Æ^``˛∂¶¸¥›Y‘Yòcı•c‡ê}]≤zÛÖÍÎ‘Æ^Ñ>_ˇÌiº˘96ruœwRMÛ…ê,π=Â…#S?$ò!\ô)Ω∆:ÏÁnÜ:kótc3Ωh1xçvø¸ûé]*ÜßMê‹'9�£E0C0UÂùY0ÇGXÃ¨˙T6Ü{:µM0Uˇ0ˇ0Uˇ0
    *ÜHÜ˜
�Ç�Ö]é‰oQhB†›ªO'%ÑΩ˜d˝-◊0„§Î⁄))∂y?vˆ#∏
˘X§‘apΩajä’
Ω≈º0|÷È%çÜ@OÏÃ£~8∆7OÌ›h1éL“≥tÓæu^Hpˇ\Ñ¿yÖ∏˝æe£¿¥¯R79’©1zø†*Ùô˜£EÇ„<^ıùûµ»û|.»§ûNKm˝pmkcΩdÊ∑ŒÚü.ª∑ÚPàsí¬‚„çö2´é›ÈÓ~5´êØ>0îz–3=ßeı¸éûbœGD,]ªµ2“G“8.–˛Å‹2jµÓ<’¸ÁÅ√$BÍc9© ```

So I removed this portion in the hopes that I'd at least have a valid file.  Not sure if that helped, because I still got the error message.

I also tried altering ActiveMerchant's `connection.rb` `configure_ssl` method, changing

`http.ca_file     = File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../certs/cacert.pem'`

to

`http.ca_file = Rails.root + "app/vendor/plugins/active_merchant/lib/certs/cacert.pem"`

I'm not sure if this actually pointed to my `cacert.pem` file correctly, since I can't write to the development log from this file.  I don't even know if this file would be used if it were pointing to the file correctly.  There is a severe lack of information about this online.

My site is down until I solve this problem.  I'm in full panic-mode.  Any ideas where I need to look/what I need to do?

Comment: I've seen this before and a rekey solved my problem.

Comment: Check this out: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Comment: My site's SSL certificate works fine.  This isn't where you specify custom certificates to be used by ActiveMerchant when connecting to Authorize.net's AIM API.  I was pointed in the direction I'm headed by Heroku Support, which told me "This looks like a Ruby app and I see a few different HTTP client libraries in here. If you go through the documentation there is usually an option called ca_path or ca_file or ca_bundle which will be a directory you add to the app containing the certificates you want to use."

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to your post I was able to get this exact issue solved. I installed the latest activemerchant gem on a different server and copied the cacert.pem from the new gem to the /vendor/plugins/active_merchant/lib/certs/ directory of my not working server. Restart Apache and was able to process cc successfully.

Might be a bit of a workaround but at least now we can accept payments again.

Comment: Glad I could (kinda?) help.  I found a different solution, which turned out to be quite simple, just not clearly documented anywhere that I've been able to find.  Hopefully, our answers help others who may be running into this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this on my own, and thankfully, it was pretty darn simple.  I'm glad I backed up my old `cacert.pem` file, too!

I simply copied the contents of the old `cacert.pem` file, and pasted that at the beginning of my new `cacert.pem` file.  I also left out the gobbledegook Baltimore CyberTrust Root certificate I mentioned above.

I also returned ActiveMerchant's `connection.rb` `configure_ssl` method back to it's original state.

**TL;DR**

Chain the new certs together *after* all the old certs in `cacert.pem`.  Boom!  Done.  Next!